# Equivalent of Notepad++ SCI_LINECOPY in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, notepad++

In Notepad++, view `Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Scintilla commands`. The command `SCI_LINECOPY`, currently assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, copies the current line to the clipboard for pasting elsewhere. Very nice!

Does Visual Studio 2019 have something similar under `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`? The `Edit.Duplicate` command, which copies the current line into the editor though not to the clipboard, is excellent but only superficially similar to `SCI_LINECOPY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, without any additional adjustment, this is a normal process as shown in the pictures below.

When the cursor is in the line (1), I can copy it to the clipboard without selecting the text first using <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

[image]

Followed of course by <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (2) or optional by step (3).

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Looks like this is part of Visual Studio's `Edit.Copy` command. If nothing is selected, then Ctrl+C copies the entire line, which is what I needed. Nice!`